# How can I align nodes and have arrows of the same length in tikz-cd?

Tags: tikz-cd

I have a small commutative diagram with nodes of varying text length. This causes the arrows between columns to be of different lengths. Basically I want each node along a column to be centred so that all arrows would be of the same length. Thanks for the help!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite, amssymb, amsmath, xcolor, amsfonts, hyperref, ulem, amsthm, enumitem, cleveref, tikz, mathtools,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[d,"\mu_0"] \arrow[r,"\mu_0"] & A\otimes A \arrow[d, 
"\mu_0\otimes\text{Id}"]\\
A\otimes A \arrow[r, "\text{Id}\otimes \mu_0"] & A\otimes A\otimes A
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution based on `eqparbox`, which adds a system of tags to the usual box constructs. All boxes sharing the same tag have the same width (the natural width of the box with this tag and the widest contents).

*Unrelated*: some of the packages you load are already loaded by others, so I removed them. Also, `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions, most notably `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite, mathtools, amssymb, xcolor, ulem, amsthm, enumitem, tikz-cd}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][N]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}
\usepackage{hyperref, cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\eqmathbox{A} \arrow[d,"\mu_0"] \arrow[r,"\mu_0"] & \eqmathbox[M]{A\otimes A} \arrow[d,"\mu_0\otimes\mathrm{Id}"]\\
\eqmathbox{A\otimes A} \arrow[r, "\mathrm{Id}\otimes \mu_0"] & \eqmathbox[M]{A\otimes A\otimes A}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 8):

You only need to adjust the text width of the nodes. (In the original version of this answer I forgot to apply this only to the nodes in the cells. The correct syntax is `cells={...}`, and not `nodes={...}` which applies the width also to the labels, which are nodes, too.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={text width={width("$A\otimes A\otimes A$")},align=center},
column sep=4em]
A \arrow[d,"\mu_0"] \arrow[r,"\mu_0"] & A\otimes A \arrow[d, 
"\mu_0\otimes\text{Id}"]\\
A\otimes A \arrow[r, "\text{Id}\otimes \mu_0"] & A\otimes A\otimes A
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]